# Display Member is not display at the first time event fired in RepositoryLookupEdit in Winforms Gridview Devexpress?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, repositorylookupedit

I used RepositoryLookupEdit in my 1st Column of Gridview. Using EditValueChanged Event remaining columns fill automatically, till now every thing is working fine. Then I call one Function inside RepositoryLookupEdit, After that very first time this EditValueChanged event fired my Display Member is not shown, it simply shows Null value that i given. Next time if I reselect same column it working fine. What was wrong here ?

```
private void repositoryItemGridLookUpEdit1_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridLookUpEdit LookupEdit = sender as GridLookUpEdit;
        DataRowView SelectedDataRow = (DataRowView)LookupEdit.GetSelectedDataRow();


        gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("Description", SelectedDataRow["ProductDescription"]);
        gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("UoM", SelectedDataRow["UnitofMeasure"]);
        gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("Quantity", SelectedDataRow["DefaultQuantity"]); //UnitPrice
        gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("UnitPrice", SelectedDataRow["MRPPrice"]);
        gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("DiscountPercentage", SelectedDataRow["Discount"]);
        gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("DiscountAmount", SelectedDataRow["DiscountAmount"]);
        gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("TaxInPercentage", SelectedDataRow["Taxid1"]);

        Taxamountcalc(); // function to calculate taxamount

        rowcount = gridView1.RowCount; 
    }
```

In this above code if i remove or comment "Taxamountcalc()" then my display member display properly if i enables this function then it show "NullText" only.

```
 private void Taxamountcalc()
    {
        if (barCheckItem1.Checked)
        {
            TaxAmount.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Decimal;
            TaxAmount.UnboundExpression = "Round([UnitTotal] * ([TaxInPercentage] / 100), 2)";
        }
        else if (!(barCheckItem1.Checked)) 
        {
            TaxAmount.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Decimal;
            TaxAmount.UnboundExpression = "Round(([UnitPrice] * ([TaxInPercentage] / 100)) * [Quantity], 2)";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some code ?

Comment: Hi Sid, I updated my question.

Comment: Thanks, can you add the code of the TaxAmountCalc() method ?

Comment: Ya i Updated but I solved this issue by calling that Function from "CheckedChanged" event, Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I'm glade you solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call any function from RepositoryLookupdit EditValueChanged Event. If we call any function from EditValueChanged Event, for the First time selecting any values from lookupedit  display Member is not displays it simply shows nulltext.

```
private void repositoryItemGridLookUpEdit1_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridLookUpEdit LookupEdit = sender as GridLookUpEdit;
    DataRowView SelectedDataRow = (DataRowView)LookupEdit.GetSelectedDataRow();


    gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("Description", SelectedDataRow["ProductDescription"]);
    gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("UoM", SelectedDataRow["UnitofMeasure"]);
    gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("Quantity", SelectedDataRow["DefaultQuantity"]); //UnitPrice
    gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("UnitPrice", SelectedDataRow["MRPPrice"]);
    gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("DiscountPercentage", SelectedDataRow["Discount"]);
    gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("DiscountAmount", SelectedDataRow["DiscountAmount"]);
    gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("TaxInPercentage", SelectedDataRow["Taxid1"]);

    //  Taxamountcalc(); 
    //  rowcount = gridView1.RowCount; 
}
```

Now it is working properly